# 500 Internal Error in ASP.NET MVC Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and MVC 4 for my web application. This is my controller code:

> public ActionResult MyController()
>
> ```
>     {
>         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
>         {
>             using (MyContainer context = new MyContainer())
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     var result = Some Query;
>
>                     return PartialView("_MyView", result);
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                     
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
>         {
>             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "User" });
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return Redirect("/");
>         }
>     }
> ```

This method will be done successfully, But my ajax container not showing any things. In firebug this error raised:

`NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error + http://localhost....?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

Why does this error occur?
What do I do to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do some basic troubleshooting, like checking if any exception is raised instead of having a blank catch clause.

Comment: Set the `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your web config and post the complete error messessage what you see in firebug

Comment: add logging to your app. e.g nlog

Comment: My view not executed. but I found a `{` in my start of view code that raised parser error. When parser error raised in application, `500 Internal Server Error` occured. :-)

Comment: I believe it is because most likely your ASP.NET application encountered some unhanded exception. I also see you are using `using`. Did you implement `IDisposable` interface for `MyContainer` type?  **_The object provided to the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources._** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @JigarPatel The code will not compile unless MyContainer does implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

The 500 Internal Server Error message might be seen in any number of ways because something was not processed fine on the server. In your case, as the commends, your `MyContainer` type does not implement `IDisposable` interface, so, you cannot use this type on the `using(){ }` block. When you use a type on a **using** block, this type have to implement IDIsposable because when it get over, the .Net Framework will remove the instance from the heap and the reference. I did some changes on your code without using block. Take a look:

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        try
        {
            MyContainer context = new MyContainer();

            var result = Some Query;
            return PartialView("_MyView", result);      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return some partial error that shows some message error
            return PartialView("_Error");
        }
    }

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "User" });
    }

    return Redirect("/");
}
```